# How does returning object properties work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, return-value

The code

```
var Foo = function(value) {
  this.val = value;
}

var foo = new Foo(2);
var boo = new Foo(3);
return foo+boo;
```

returns `[object Object][object Object]`. This makes sense to me because they *are* objects. But this amended version of the code returns `5`:

```
var Foo = function(value) {
  this.val = value;
}

Foo.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  return this.val;
}

var foo = new Foo(2);
var boo = new Foo(3);
return foo+boo;
```

Why? I would have thought that `foo.val` and `boo.val` would be required to produce such a result. I would have also thought that `valueOf`would need to be called in order for it to have any effect on the returned values.

I have looked at some JavaScript documentation pertaining to `valueOf()` at Mozilla Developer Network (it was recommended reading for this problem), but I still don't understand what's going on here. (Side note: I also don't understand how a function can be called without the parentheses following it...)

I am looking for an answer that explains some of the underlying mechanics/processes of objects while still being accessible to someone who is new to objects. Thanks!

Comment: In the second instance you're redefining what `valueOf()` returns. By default on objects, `valueOf()` returns `[object Object]`. You can also redefine `toString()` for other interesting results when concatinating into a string.

Comment: @PatrickGunderson So, to clarify, the amendment redefines the _method_ `object.valueOf()` that every object already has?

Comment: @QueenCode that is Correct.

Comment: `+` can call `valueOf` or `toString` or both. Which one is called first depends on the type of object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy: "JavaScript calls the valueOf method to convert an object to a primitive value." ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)) You are defining `valueOf()`, which is called upon to provide a value for an object when used in an operation.

It goes on to say:

> If an object has no primitive value, valueOf returns the object
>   itself, which is displayed as:
>
> [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

You gave your constructor's prototype a `.valueOf()` function that returns the `val` property. That function is what's consulted by the operation of the `+` operator.

When neither operand is a string, the innards call an internal "ToNumber" function to get the operand values. That, in turn, will try the `valueOf` function on object values if it exists. In your case, it does.